# Rails 3 Engines: how to change the priority of your routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

I am working on extracting some of the functionality of one of my apps into an Engine.
It seems that the routes in your app are generated and then the routes for the engine. The end result is that my engine routes are considered low priority and my app routes are eating up all the requests before they ever get to the engine routes. Is there way for me to control the priority of my engine routes?

Comment: Map Your Engine Inside a Namespace maybe..

Answer (score 0):

According to this discussion:
http://groups.google.com/group/blacklight-development/browse_thread/thread/a22ee4636a70b485

it used to be the other way around.

You might be able to figure out how to reverse it by digging into what changes they made when they fixed it.

Specifically this one has a hack that overrode plugin routes with app routes by loading the class inside of the Routing::RouteSet class
http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/159805560/tips-for-writing-your-own-rails-engine

Obviously it's older rails - but I figured you might get some inspiration for your own needs :)